# Can a reinforced hose develop an internal restriction due to thermal expansion?

Tags: reinforcement, thermal-expansion

The type of hose involved is the thinnest one on the right in this [picture](http://www.flexiblerubberhoses.com/photo/pl6863074-id_8mm_to_22mm_epdm_air_conditioning_hose_for_conveying_r134a_r12_etc.jpg). This hose contains an external rubber layer, a textile reinforcement layer, an inner rubber layer and a nylon lining.

The hose has been ziptied to a plastic electrical conduit and it serves as a discharge hose of an automotive air conditioner, so it gets warm during the system operation, and internal pressures are high (the reason for the reinforcement layer).
Also, it's located not very far from the exhaust plumbing.

Can the zip tie and the conduit possibly restrict the hose internally due to thermal expansion as the hose warms up, or would the zip tie expand together with the hose? Can the reinforcement layer prevent the hose from developing a restriction except in the case of a lining delamination?

Here's an exemplificative picture of the arrangement:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the zip tie and conduit won't cause the pipe to develop an internal restriction.

Even squeezing the outer cover will not compress the inner sleeve... There are metal pipe clamps that will compress the inner but they have serious leverage that you won't get from a nylon zip tie.

Comment: You're right. I've tried choking a discarded piece of a rubber gas stove pipe (which has an internal plastic sleeve too, but no reinforcement braid) with a nylon ziptie, and no restriction developed. I had to tighten a metal clamp with a serious torque to watch the inner sleeve begin to deform.